# Bucle While se cicla al realizar consulta

Tags: php, mysql, while

estoy realizando una consulta de una BD para descartar los días festivos y días Domingo de un rango de fechas, el problema es que el método lo realicé en un While, y este se me cicla, me dí cuenta que que se cicla en el método if porque puse un break pero no sé si hay forma de que realice las operaciones correctamente, les adjunto el código

```
 while($row=$resultado->fetch_assoc())
    {
     while($row[$FechaI] != $row[$FechaF]){
            echo date("d-m-Y",strtotime($row[$FechaI])).'<br>';     
            if($row[$FechaI] != $row1['DFFecha'] || date("w",strtotime($row[$FechaI]))!=0){
                
                $aux = date("d-m-Y",strtotime($row[$FechaI]."+ 1 days"));
                echo date("d-m-Y",strtotime($aux)).'<br>';
                $row[$FechaI] = $aux;
                $contador_dias++; 
            }
            else{
                    echo date("d-m-Y",strtotime($aux)).'<br>';
                    $aux = date("d-m-Y",strtotime($row[$FechaI]."+ 1 days"));
                    $row[$FechaI] = $aux;
            }
            //$row[$FechaI]=strtotime($row[$FechaI]."+ 1 days");
            break;
        }
       
        echo 'El proceso tardó '.($contador_dias).' días'.'<br>';
        $contador_dias = 0;
        
    }
}
```

Comment: No creo que tenga nada que ver, pero en el código de tu pregunta le sobra una llave final `}`

Comment: ¿Y que es `$row1['DFFecha']`?  ¿de donde sale?  ¿cuantos bucles tienes ahi metidos?

Comment: Veo que cambias el formato de fecha en $row[$FechaI] pero no en $row[$FechaF], asi nunca coincidiran

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Diria que pueden ser dos problemas:

1. No se ve de donde sale la variable `$row1['DFFecha']`
2. cambias el formato de fecha en `$row[$FechaI]` pero no en `$row[$FechaF]`, asi nunca coincidiran

Te dejo este cacho de código que sí funciona "omitiendo" esos dos temas. Fíjate que la fecha final la he puesto al reves para que la condición del  `while` se pueda cumplir dado el cambio de formato que haces sobre la fecha inicial.

```php
    $fechaInicial = "2022/01/10";
    $fechaFinal = "20-01-2022";
    $contador_dias = 0;

    while ($fechaInicial != $fechaFinal) {

        echo date("d-m-Y",strtotime($fechaInicial)).'<br>';     

        if(date("w",strtotime($fechaInicial))!=0) {

            $aux = date("d-m-Y",strtotime($fechaInicial."+ 1 days"));

            echo date("d-m-Y",strtotime($aux)).'<br>';
            $fechaInicial = $aux;
            $contador_dias++; 

        } else {
            echo date("d-m-Y",strtotime($aux)).'<br>';

            $aux = date("d-m-Y",strtotime($fechaInicial."+ 1 days"));
            $fechaInicial = $aux;
        }
    }
    echo 'El proceso tardó '.($contador_dias).' días'.'<br>';
    $contador_dias = 0;
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, sí me di cuenta de algunos errores, me sirvió muchísimo!